How can I detect if some application/software/tools is set to always on top using Node.js
I want to create tracking software, which can track which application/software/tools is open currently. Basically I want to get current Active Window. In case If you have multiple screens then I want to get current active window in both the screens.
I also want to check if there's any software/tools running which keeps some software always keep on top, if possible.
How can I achieve this using Node.js.
Is there any specific library available for this?
I tried some low level C++ Code and compile it using node-gyp and ran it. I was able to get current active window, but it is only for single screen, What if I have multiple screen and two different program is opened in those screen? I want those two programs.
Here's C++ Code:
addon.cc file
#include <napi.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <Psapi.h> 

Napi::Object GetActiveWindowInfo(const Napi::CallbackInfo& info) {
    Napi::Env env = info.Env();

    HWND hwnd = GetForegroundWindow();
    const int nMaxCount = 256;
    TCHAR szWindowTitle[nMaxCount];
    DWORD pid;

    // Retrieve the window title
    GetWindowText(hwnd, szWindowTitle, nMaxCount);

    // Retrieve the process ID (PID) of the active window
    GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, &pid);

    // Get the process handle using the PID
    HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION | PROCESS_VM_READ, FALSE, pid);

    TCHAR szProcessName[MAX_PATH] = TEXT("<unknown>");
    if (hProcess != NULL) {
        // Retrieve the process name
        GetModuleFileNameEx(hProcess, NULL, szProcessName, MAX_PATH);
        CloseHandle(hProcess);
    }

    // Construct the return object
    Napi::Object result = Napi::Object::New(env);
    result.Set("title", Napi::String::New(env, szWindowTitle));
    result.Set("processName", Napi::String::New(env, szProcessName));

    return result;
}

Napi::Object Init(Napi::Env env, Napi::Object exports) {
    exports.Set("getActiveWindowInfo", Napi::Function::New(env, GetActiveWindowInfo));
    return exports;
}

NODE_API_MODULE(addon, Init)

binding.gyp file
{
  "targets": [
    {
      "target_name": "addon",
      "sources": [ "addon.cc" ],
      "include_dirs": [
        "<!@(node -p \"require('node-addon-api').include\")"
      ],
      "cflags!": [ "-fno-exceptions" ],
      "cflags_cc!": [ "-fno-exceptions" ],
      "defines": [
        "NAPI_CPP_EXCEPTIONS" 
      ],
      "libraries": []
    }
  ]
}

app.js file
const addon = require("./build/Release/addon.node");

setInterval(() => {
  const windowInfo = addon.getActiveWindowInfo();
  console.log("Window Title:", windowInfo.title);
  console.log("Process Name:", windowInfo.processName);
}, 1000);

package.json file
{
  "name": "addon",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Node.js addon",
  "main": "addon.cc",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "node-gyp configure build"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "node-addon-api": "^8.0.0"
  }
}

How to Run
npm install
npm run build
node app.js
